# how to add different sized gaps between the different items in a html list?

Tags: html, css

i have got a list which appears horizontal on my html. 
but i would like the first 4 elements to appear in the middle of the screen with the same gap between them and then i want the last element in the list to be in the top right hand corner?

```
<ul id="navigationBarList">
  <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Bookings">Bookings</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Blog">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Pricing">Pricing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Sign In">Sign In</a></li>
</ul>
```

everything I have tried has not worked so far. I assume it would be about giving an id or something to the individual items but that for some reason has zero effect

this is the css:

```
#navigationBarList{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: black;    
    font-size: 25px;
    color: red;
    width: 100%;
}
#navigationBarList li{
    display: inline;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/3Ly6advj/

Comment: @SleekGeek take a look at this website. 'http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/30-html-best-practices-for-beginners--net-4957'. I am attempting to get my nav bar similar looking to that. if you think there's has 2 lists then do you know how to put 2 lists on the same horizontal line? thanks

Comment: @BlackMagma check out my fiddle at jsfiddle.net/3Ly6advj

Comment: @KevinVoorn yours seems good. only issue when i drag to make the box bigger the sign in has issues

Answer (score 2):

It's not 'really' a menu item as such in this context. Use a different element outside of the menu which can then be positioned anyway you want.

```css
#navigationBarList {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#navigationBarList li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
nav {
  position: relative;
}
#login {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="navigationBarList">
    <li><a href="#About">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Bookings">Bookings</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Blog">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Pricing">Pricing</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <a id="login" href="#Sign In">Sign In</a>
</nav>
```

**NOTE:** - I should point out that you can **still** leave the `#SignIn` link as a list item if you so wish but, in that case, the  parent `ul` should receive `position:relative` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Paulie you have an extra ">" in you HTML

Answer (score 0):

You could use a psuedo-selector for the last element

`#navigationBarList li:last{ /* css */ }`

Or give it an ID and style just that ID which will have more specificity

`<li id="signin"><a href="#Sign In">Sign In</a></li>`

`#navigationBarList li#signin{ /* css */ }`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this. Using "margin: auto" to center align the text and adding an extra container.
I also assume you want the space between link text to be equal and not the whole width that each link spans.

```
#navigationBar{
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: black;    
    font-size: 25px;
    color: red;
    width: 100%;
}

#navigationBarList{
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
    width:600px;
}
#navigationBarList li{
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left:20px;
}

#navigationBarList li:last-child{
   position:absolute;
   right:20px;
}

<div id="navigationBar">
<ul id="navigationBarList">
  <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Bookings">Bookings</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Blog">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Pricing">Pricing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Sign In">Sign In</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```